# Javascript store backbone model instance in object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, instance

I am trying to store created instances in an object, unfortunatly it keeps producing errors like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

This is an example of my Backbone model code:

```
Hero = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id:         0,
        name:       ''
    },

    initialize: function(){
    }
});
```

and this is the way I try to create and store the instances

```
var heroes = {
    new Hero({ 0, 'Orrin'}),
    new Hero({ 1, 'Valeska'})
}
```

How am I supposed to store these instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Hero({ 0, 'Orrin'}),
new Hero({ 1, 'Valeska'})
```

That's not valid Javascript.  You sort of combined an array and an object; you should either do:

```
new Hero([ 0, 'Orrin']),
new Hero([ 1, 'Valeska'])
```

(which is valid Javascript, but not valid Backbone) ... or, more likely:

```
new Hero({index: 0, name: 'Orrin'}),
new Hero({index: 1, name: 'Valeska'})
```

Comment: The backbone tutorials which I've found didn't tell me this but it seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  In defense of those tutorials, they probably assumed a base-line level of Javascript understanding.  As much as I personally <3 Backbone, you might get a little more "bang for your buck" by focusing on your Javascript fundamentals before tackling Backbone; just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

did you notice that 
`defaults: {
        id:         0,
        name:       '',
    },` there is a ',' at the end of 'name' attribute? Try to delete it and see if that would fix the problem.

Comment: sorry, I copied only part of my code, in the original code this is not the case